# entering date into database through three dropdownlists for day, month, and year

Tags: asp.net

I am using three dropdownlists for day, month, and year simultaneously and concatenating their results to generate a string in format 12/12/1999. But as the database table's field type is datetime it does not support this format.

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: You've basically answered it yourself. You have 3 dropdowns and YOU format the date into that bad format. So... change how you format the date.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);`

This is prefered approach since string-date parsing works based on culture. In some cultures this will be valid, on others not: `15/3/2011` / `3/15/2011`.

Also see `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.ParseExact()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how you can convert it to .Net DateTime type:

```
 DateTime newentry = Convert.ToDateTime("12/12/1999");
```

Comment: I have used this solution but it is not working..

Comment: Provide more code how you're saving the values to your DB? Are you using any ORM or directly writing it via SQL?